WPF Navigation Switching views
I'm writing a simple example program that switches the view when the button is clicked, as shown below.
Page1Model
namespace Step3_1.Models.Page1
{
    class Page1Model
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
}

Page2Model
namespace Step3_1.Models.Page2
{
    class Page2Model
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}

Page1VM
namespace Step3_1.ViewModels.Page1
{
    class Page1VM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Models.Page1.Page1Model _page1Model;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _page1Model.name; }
            set { _page1Model.name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public int age
        {
            get { return _page1Model.age; }
            set { _page1Model.age = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public Page1VM()
        {
            InitializeVM();
        }

        private void InitializeVM()
        {
            _page1Model = new Models.Page1.Page1Model();
        }

    }
}

Page2VM
namespace Step3_1.ViewModels.Page2
{
    class Page2VM :ViewModelBase
    {
        private Models.Page2.Page2Model _page2Model;

        public string Message
        {
            get { return _page2Model.message; }
            set { _page2Model.message = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public Page2VM()
        {
            InitializeVM();
        }

        private void InitializeVM()
        {
            _page2Model = new Models.Page2.Page2Model();
        }



    }
}

Page1View
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:Page1VM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Name : "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Gainsboro"  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Age : "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding age}" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

Page2View
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:Page2VM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Aquamarine"  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Message : "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Message}" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

MainWindowVM
namespace Step3_1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private object _currentVM;
        public object CurrentVM
        {
            get { return _currentVM; }
            set { _currentVM = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private Page1.Page1VM _page1VM;
        private Page2.Page2VM _page2VM;

        public ICommand Page1Command { get; set; }
        private void Page1(object obj)
        {
            CurrentVM = _page1VM;
        }

        public ICommand Page2Command { get; set; }
        private void Page2(object obj)
        {
            CurrentVM = _page2VM;
        }

        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            InitializeVM();
            SwitchToFirstView();
        }

        private void InitializeVM()
        {
            _page1VM = new Page1.Page1VM();
            _page2VM = new Page2.Page2VM();

            Page1Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Page1);
            Page2Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Page2);
        }

        private void SwitchToFirstView()
        {
            CurrentVM = _page1VM;
        }



    }
}

MainWindow
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Beige" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Page1" Width="100" Command="{Binding Page1Command}"/>
            <Button Content="Page2" Width="100" Command="{Binding Page2Command}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>


I can't see the view switching. Is there a way?
Also, how to use Datamplate in this code and the disadvantage is that View Instance continues to be created, and I hope it's only created once for the first time.
Is there a better way other than DataTemplate? I'd like to know how it's commonly used.
Please let me know if there is a most basic example of a View changing (Switching) using a WPF MVVM.

Thank you

Using DataTemplate is the way to go. Take out the VM setting from the user control xaml. Refer to the following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67635203/wpf-datatemplate-binding-for-different-usercontrol

Add DataTemplate definitions in MainWindow:
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type page1:Page1VM}">
            <local:Page1View/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type page2:Page2VM}">
            <local:Page2View/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

Take out the Setting of the DataContext from the Page1View and Page2View XAML.
The approach is view model first as you planned well. When CurrentVM is set with the appropriate view model, there is an automatic mechanism in WPF to search a way to display the ContentControl. If nothing is found, WPF take a display from the ToString() method we have in each class. But first it search the resources for an appropriate DataTemplate to fit the view model in hand.

Thank you so much for your response.
I went through it as above, but every time I switch View, View instances continue to be created, is there a way to solve this?
It's stuck here and can't proceed. Please help.

Please note that with this solution, you should not instantiate the DataContext in the XAML.
