Navigation Services from LoginWindow to my MainWindow,
I'm new to using WPF and using MVVM pattern. I try to make 2 Windows which is LoginWindow and MainWindow which will have UserControl such as HomeView in it. I initialize my Service Provider in my App.xaml.cs like this
public App()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddSingleton(Provider => new LoginPage
    {
        DataContext = Provider.GetRequiredService<LoginViewModel>()
    });
    services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationServices>();
    services.AddSingleton<Func<Type, ViewModel>>(serviceProvider => viewModelType => (ViewModel)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(viewModelType));
    
    serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    
    if(serviceProvider != null)
    {
        var loginPage = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<LoginPage>();
        loginPage.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Service Provider is null");
    }
    
}

and my App.xaml looked like this
<Application x:Class="NewHRD.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NewHRD"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:NewHRD.MVVM.ViewModels"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:NewHRD.MVVM.Views">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeName=viewModel:MainViewModel}">
            <view:MainWindow/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeName=viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
            <view:HomeView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>


From the code I've given, I make the LoginPage as the first Window to show, and when a user is logged in, MainWindow will show up. but the thing is when I Navigate to my MainWindow like this
private async void ExecuteLoginCommand(object arg)
{
    string valid = await APIUser.AuthenticateUser("user/Login", Username, Password);
    if (valid != null)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(valid);

        // Extract the "data" part from the JObject
        JToken dataToken = jsonObject["data"];
        Dictionary<string, object> data = dataToken.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        DynamicModel dynamicModel = new DynamicModel(data);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity(Username), new string[] { data["access_rights_name"].ToString() });
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);
        if (MessageBox.Show($"Masuk sebagai {Username} ?", "Logged In", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
            MessageBoxImage.Information) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            IsHomeButtonVisible = "Visible";
            Window curWind = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
            Navigation.NavigateTo<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hmmm...");
    }

When I debug my program, it actually enters the MainViewModel, but the view doesn't change. Can anyone help me with it. Thankyou.
I expected for the MainView to show up when I Navigate to MainViewModel.
Edit
Class which I use to navigate to different pages.
    public interface INavigationService
    {
        ViewModel CurrentView { get; }
    
        void NavigateTo<T>() where T : ViewModel;
    }
    internal class NavigationServices : ObservableObject, INavigationService
    {
        private readonly Func<Type, ViewModel> _viewModelFactory;
        private ViewModel _currentView;
    
        public ViewModel CurrentView
        {
            get => _currentView;
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public NavigationServices(Func<Type, ViewModel> viewModelFactory)
        {
            _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
        }
        public void NavigateTo<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModel
        {
            ViewModel viewModel = _viewModelFactory.Invoke(typeof(TViewModel));
            CurrentView = viewModel;
        }

}


Suggest looking at a more simple question/solution regarding basic navigation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78258970/wpf-navigation-switching-views/78262391#78262391

You could take a look at https://github.com/AndyONeill/LoginNavigation

Why do you show your IoC container configuration but not the navigation logic? Your code does not show anything navigation related...

In general, a page should not have any information about the navigation context e.g.  next screen or the previous screen. This is difficult to maintain and introduces unnecessary dependencies and probably leads to classes sharing too much information. Instead, move navigation to a single class that knows all this context details. Then let your view model classes raise events e.g. LoginCompleted. The navigation class can listen to this event and decide what screen to load next.

The only reason that a screen should navigate on its own is to navigate in its own context e.g. when it wants to show child screens.

I use another class called NavigationServices to navigate from page to page. I'll edit the question to include said class. I learn this from a youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFzmBZpjuAo&t=91s
